# I'm not Important

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is better than you
>
> My infix is something to help you heal
>
> My suffix is something you did in the past
>
> I am something you will do later

What am I?

Comment: Wow, 7 down-voters and none of them cared to explain why to the poster...

Comment: Check the comments on the answer...

Answer (score 7):

May I be ..

> **Procrastinate**? PRO-CREATIN-ATE
>
>  a **Pro** is better than me
>
>  **Creatin** can help heal...but I am not sure what its real medical effect is
>
>  I **ate** a few times in the past...

Comment: This was what I was thinking too but I couldn't figure out a way to make the infix work. The only thing I could rationalize was (rot13)"ceb-PNFG-vangr".

Comment: This is correct!

Comment: "ceb-PERNGVAR-ngr" is the answer? That's not even a word...this is a stretch for a Riley Riddle. "ceb-PNFG-vangr" is a stretch too.

Comment: I fixed my spelling (that was the french version of it). Also, @zeethreepio, I think PotatoLatte meant that your infix is the correct version. It has a closer meaning and is not as much a stretch

Comment: So angry I wasted time trying to figure this one out when the answer isn't even composed of the individual words. But well done for getting the right answer against insurmountable odds.